# Angular2 Form Input - Cannot fill in text

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I created a component which is generating a form according to the current page:

```html
<div *ngIf="checkCurrentDetails() == 'Dimension'" >

<form [formGroup]="form">
<div formGroupName="name">
  <input formControlName="first" placeholder="First">
  <input formControlName="last" placeholder="Last">
</div>
<input formControlName="email" placeholder="Email">
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
<p>Value: {{ form.value | json }}</p>
<p>Validation status: {{ form.status }}</p>


</div>
<div *ngIf="checkCurrentDetails() == 'Dimension Attributes'" >

 <form [formGroup]="form">
  <div formGroupName="name">
  <input class="search" formControlName="first" placeholder="First">
  <input formControlName="last" placeholder="Last">
 </div>
 <input formControlName="email" placeholder="Email">
 <button>Submit</button>
 </form>
 <p>Value: {{ form.value | json }}</p>
 <p>Validation status: {{ form.status }}</p>

 </div>
```

With this test method:

```js
    checkCurrentDetails(){
        if(this.currentDetails['site'] == 'Dimension Attributes'){
           this.form = this.fb.group({
               name: this.fb.group({
                  first: ['Nancy', Validators.minLength(2)],
                last: 'Drew',
            }),
            email: '',
        });
        return this.currentDetails['site'];
    }
    if(this.currentDetails['site'] == 'Dimension'){
        this.form = this.fb.group({
            name: this.fb.group({
                first: ['Nanci', Validators.minLength(2)],
                last: 'Drew',
            }),
            email: '',
        });
        return this.currentDetails['site'];
    }
}
```

it is generating the form according to the site very well and it is producing this form:

http://www.pic-upload.de/view-32540301/test.jpg.html

In the textboxes youll be able to see the predefined test content. For example first textbox :"Nanci" etc.
But now to my problem. I am not able to type in ,change or insert text to these textboxes. It seems like something is blocking it.

So I tried another thing to test if it has something to do with the form. I created a textbox

```
<input type='text'>
```

outside the form, which is working well. I am able to input text to this box but not to the textboxes inside the form and I don't know why?

Comment: Could you expand on *"not able to input or change the text of these forms"*? Can you not type into the controls in the browser? Does your subscription to `valueChanges` not get triggered?

Comment: You mean that you can enter in textboxes or you dont see entered data in form Object?

Comment: I am not able to type in text in the texboxes. It seems like something is blocking the input of the form. Btw, I am able to type text to a textbox which is not connected to the form.

Comment: Please give a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I changed the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `<div *ngIf="checkCurrentDetails() == 'Dimension Attributes'">`.

When you type in the textbox, ChangeDetection will run and the template is re-evaluated. As a result each time you type in the textbox, the `checkCurrentDetails()` function is getting called and the form is getting re-created/rendered! Therefore you see the initial state of the form again and again and get a feeling that the typing is being blocked.

Simply change it to

`<div *ngIf="currentDetails.site == 'Dimension Attributes'">` and it works!

Here is the Plunker link for working sample:
http://plnkr.co/edit/psjqZZvfx7GyOVAgkSJj?p=preview

Comment: Hello Sir and thank you for the response. This is working, but not the solution of the problem. I want to explain this. This is a details pannel, so I want to render a form according to the site title which is changing by :

     constructor(_globalService: GlobalService,private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.currentDetails = _globalService.currentTitle;
        this.subscription = _globalService.nameChange.subscribe((value) => {
            this.currentDetails = JSON.parse(value);
        });

Comment: For example: We have site1, site2, site3. Inside the main component is a detailspannel.component.A global service is changing the title of the site. I want to change the form inside the details pannel according to the site title. If it is site1 the form is rendered with 3 fields.. If its site2, lets say I need 10 fields etc.

Comment: In that case, you have to execute the logic for deciding the form type in the component code. You can put that in single variable. and use that `variable` with `*ngIf` or `*ngSwitch` to render the appropriate form. If you call the function itself in `*ngIf`, the change detection of Angular2 will execute it each time there is a change in your current form. Hope you understand now.

Comment: Subscribe to the global service, and whenever you receive a change in subscribed value, execute the logic to find which form is to be displayed and save that in a variable. On yout HTML template, use that value with `*ngIf*` to display the appropriate form.